# A4 portfolio as a book in photoshop. page compilation?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, page-layout, design-principles, book

i want to design my A4 portfolio like a book format. and want to design 2 pages at a time. Could you suggest how shall i go about it. I was thinking of taking pages (1,4-2,3) and (5,8-6,7) together. Since i was wondering how they would be printed and put together to be bound as a book.

Comment: If you have a chance to use indesign or even illustrator, definitely go with either of them. If you don't have access to those two, you should maybe try Scribus, which is open source. Photoshop just isn't meant to produce multiple pages.

Comment: I would *never* use Photoshop for a multi-page project.

Comment: Also be aware, using Photoshop..... if you intend to distribute this booklet as a PDF, people reviewing this PDF will know you've used Photoshop. That *will* reflect upon your abilities and awareness of proper tool usage. If that matters to them, the very fact you've used Photoshop could be very detrimental.

Comment: On a side node, a A4 with 2 pages on it for a portfolio is VERY small. It's just a suggestion but you should use one page per A4 to make sure the details of your designs are clearly visible.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as Scott said, I would never advise you use Photoshop for this kind of project. Photoshop is not intended for multiple page print projects while InDesign is designed **specifically** for them. In fact, InDesign has a Print Booklet feature that will re-arrange your pages upon export so you don't even have to worry about this.

That being said, regardless of what you're using to design your A4 booklet, I would set up your pages like this:

Page 1, Side 1: [8|1]

Page 1, Side 2: [2|7]

Page 2, Side 1: [6|3]

Page 2, Side 2: [4|5]